# Enable pagination for gutenberg latest posts block

Tags: javascript, wordpress, pagination, react-redux, wordpress-gutenberg

I'd like to add pagination to the latest posts gutenberg block. This block fetches posts through `withSelect()` and `getEntityRecords()`, similar to the [block editor handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/block-tutorial/creating-dynamic-blocks/).

The REST API returns two handy header fields for use in pagination:
"X-WP-Total" and "X-WP-TotalPages"

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/pagination/

Does anyone know if its possible to access these header fields in a dynamic block which fetches posts through `withSelect()` and `getEntityRecords()` and set state for the total number of pages and the current page?

Here's the simplyfied version of block.js:

```
( function( blocks, element, data ) {

  var registerBlockType = blocks.registerBlockType,
      withSelect = data.withSelect;

  registerBlockType( 'mdwpb/latest-posts', {
    title: 'latest posts',
    icon: 'megaphone',
    category: 'widgets',
    attributes: {},
    edit: withSelect( function( select ) {
      return {

        // here's where the magic happens, I think..
        posts: select( 'core' ).getEntityRecords( 'postType', 'post', {per_page: 1, page: 1})
        numberOfPages: ?,

      };
    } )( function( props ) {

      if ( ! props.posts ) {
        return "Loading...";
      }

      if ( props.posts.length === 0 ) {
        return "No posts";
      }
      var className = props.className;
      var post = props.posts[ 0 ];

      return (
        <div>
        { props.posts.map( ( post ) => (
        <h3 className={props.className}>
        {post.title.rendered}
        </h3>
       ))}
     </div>

    );
  } ),
} );
}(
  window.wp.blocks,
  window.wp.element,
  window.wp.data,
) );
```

I tried adding the numberOfPages to the withSelect function through an apiFetch:

```
numberOfPages: wp.apiFetch({
  path: wp.url.addQueryArgs( 'wp/v2/posts', {per_page: 1, page: 1} ),
  parse: false,
}).then( response => { return response.headers.get('X-WP-TotalPages'); } ),
```

This kindof works, but I get a promise when I use `console.log` of the numberOfPages prop in the `function(props)`. So I feel adding a apiFetch to the withSelect is not the way to go, or is it?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a solution to properly get the number of pages, but what I did as a workaround is to run an additional `getEntityRecords` query for once with the same parameters as the main one, only switching the order the other way around (setting `orderby` parameter to `asc` or `desc`) and limiting it to only one item (`per_page` set to `1`). From this I get the last item in my target set. Once I have that, I can compare the ID with all the ID's of the entities returned by the main pagination query. As soon as I find the ID of the last item in the set returned by the main query, I know this was the last page, so I can disable the "load next page" button or so.

It is not a full value solution, as it lacks the ability to tell in advance how many pages there will be, but still better than leaving the user clicking on "load more" to no avail until they give up.